# Process PHP form on hidden page, but stay on same page. No Ajax, pure php only (project)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to PHP, and I'm sure this is a common think to do, but 99% of the answers I have found to this involve AJAX, JQuery and/or JavaScript.

I am **only allowed to use HTML/CSS and PHP** in my project, so I need a working option that does not involve anything else.

I have the following setup:

- index.php, this holds my form structure
- insert.php, this sanitizes/validates and inserts form data into a database table

Leaving action as insert.php sends me to my insert.php page, which I want to keep private and for developer eyes only...no good.

```
form action=" " method="post"
// OR
form action="index.php" method="post">
```

Leaving action blank or as index.php keeps me on the same page, but...

 I want to keep my form processing in a **separate file** (insert.php) and **NOT** on the same page, if at all possible.

Do I have any options for this that are not excessively complex in pure PHP?

Thanks for any advice. 

*(PS. If there's any blatant errors or poor form here, I'm all ears to constructive criticism)*

Here's a snapshot of my insert.php file if its helpful. I can upload my form as well, but its very basic (just select a course, input first/last name, input student id).

```
// Clean the data coming from the MySQL tables
$course_clean = htmlentities($_POST['course_id']);
$stu_name_clean = htmlentities($_POST['first_last']);
$stu_id_clean = htmlentities($_POST['stu_id']);

// Escape user input coming from forms
$course = mysqli_real_escape_string($open, $_REQUEST['course_id']);
$stu_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($open, $_REQUEST['first_last']);
$stu_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($open, $_REQUEST['stu_id']);

// INSERT DATA 
    $insert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO enrolled (course_id, stu_id) VALUES ('$course', '$stu_id')";
    if(mysqli_query($open, $insert)){
        echo "Records added successfully to ENROLLED.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not add records to ENROLLED. " . mysqli_error($open);
    }
```

Comment: `If there's any blatant errors or poor form here` - yes, your sql is potentially vulnerable to sql injection and you should be using `prepared statements`

Comment: This is an introductory class to PHP and MySQL and prepared statements are not part of the course I am in, the one I am taking after this covers advanced PHP which includes the use of prepared statements. Thanks for your input and concern however! I appreciate the advice, and would not have known that fact until next term. @RamRaider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be what you want:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    require "insert.php";
}
?>
<html><head></head><body>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="course_id"><br/>
        <input type="text" name="first_last"><br/>
        <input type="text" name="stu_id"><br/>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Appreciated! I'll run it and see how it goes.

Comment: It worked exactly as it needed to! I am able to stay on the same page while inputting the data successfully. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to submit the page to itself and check if the `$_POST` is empty or not. If it's empty show the form of the page if not insert the data into the database.

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST)):
    // Clean the data coming from the MySQL tables
    $course_clean = htmlentities($_POST['course_id']);
    $stu_name_clean = htmlentities($_POST['first_last']);
    $stu_id_clean = htmlentities($_POST['stu_id']);

    // Escape user input coming from forms
    $course = mysqli_real_escape_string($open, $_REQUEST['course_id']);
    $stu_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($open, $_REQUEST['first_last']);
    $stu_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($open, $_REQUEST['stu_id']);

    // INSERT DATA 
    $insert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO enrolled (course_id, stu_id) VALUES ('$course', '$stu_id')";
    if(mysqli_query($open, $insert)){
        echo "Records added successfully to ENROLLED.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not add records to ENROLLED. " . mysqli_error($open);
    }
else: ?>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="course_id"><br/>
        <input type="text" name="first_last"><br/>
        <input type="text" name="stu_id"><br/>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```